# java.naming.CommunicationException: (mydomain name):636(port) [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect]

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, active-directory, ldap

This is my following java code, where I try to authenticate administrator by setting up ssl in active directory and java.

```
public class Unicode_passwordLdap{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        LdapContext ctx = null;
        
        try{
            Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C://Java//jre1.8.0_331//lib//security//cacerts");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C://Java//jre1.8.0_331//lib//security//cacerts");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","changeit");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
            String baseName = ",CN=Users,DC=trial,DC=com";
            Hashtable env = new Hashtable();  
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,  "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");  
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "Simple");  
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=administrator" + baseName);  //"tom@trial.com"
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "admin1*");  //"Panda123*"
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://WS2K19.trail.com:636"); //dc=trial,dc=com
            //ldaps://WS2K19.trail.com:636
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
            ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env,null); 
            System.out.println("Connection Successfull");
}catch(Exception e){
            //System.out.println("Password Cannot be Changed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the following error I get, when I run this java code:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: WS2K19.trail.com:636 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:235)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.<init>(LdapClient.java:137)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getInstance(LdapClient.java:1615)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2847)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:348)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxFromUrl(LdapCtxFactory.java:225)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:189)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:243)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:154)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:84)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:694)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
        at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154)
        at Unicode_passwordLdap.main(Unicode_passwordLdap.java:63)
```

Could someone help to solve this error!!!

Comment: Connection timeout is pretty routine part of network connections. If you were connected and then got disconnected, the answer is to lengthen the amount of time until timeout, or to send automatic "pings" back and forth. If you never connected, the issue is likely to be with authorization handshake. I myself have seen this quite a bit

Comment: How to lengthen the amount of time  in active directory or how to send automatic pings. Could you refer me some website to do this.

Comment: A connection timeout means: "No reply came back from the server and we stopped waiting." Lengthening the timeout probably won't help. It's more likely that either the server name is wrong, or the server is not listening on port 636, or there is no network path from your computer to the server (maybe because of a firewall).